# Change bubble size in altair without changing font size

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to create a altair bubble chart. The sample code and sample dataframe is below:
I want the size of the bubble based on Market_cap and put names of companies alongside. The problem is font size of names is also changing as per the bubble size.

**How can this I create this bubble chart with different bubble size but same size of font for Company names**?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Company' : ['Apple', 'Microsoft', 'Meta', 'Nvidia'],
                   'Rev_perct' : [30, 50, 90, 10],
                  'Score' : [8, 5, 10, 4],
                  'Market_Cap' : [2000, 1000, 500, 800]
})

Graph_1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(size = 100).encode( y = alt.Y('Rev_perct'), x = alt.X('Score'), 
                                                       color=alt.condition(
                                                       "datum.Rev_perct > 30"
                                                       "& datum.Score > 6",  
                                                        alt.value('red'),     
                                                       alt.value('green')          
                                                       ), size='Market_Cap')

Text_1 = Graph_1.mark_text( align='center',
   baseline='line-top', color = 'black', fontSize = 12, angle = 0,
   dy=10, dx= -5    
).encode(text='Company:O')

(Graph_1 + Text_1).properties(width = 800, height = 400)
```

This is the resulting graph i am getting now-
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your are building the `mark_text` chart from the `mark_circle` chart where you specified the size encoding, so it is inherited for the text. Either change the order in which you create the plots or unset the size encoding by passing the corresponding empty Altair encoding class (`alt.Size()`) in this case:

```
Text_1 = Graph_1.mark_text(
    align='center',
    baseline='line-top',
    color='black',
    fontSize=12,
    angle=0,
    dy=10,
    dx= -5    
).encode(
    text='Company:O',
    size=alt.Size()
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I get the following error on using the size = alt.Size() method---
SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification
 altair.vegalite.v4.schema.channels.ColorValue, validating 'additionalProperties'
 Additional properties are not allowed ('test' was unexpected)
.  
I also tried changing the graph order but then also get the size of names different in that case too

Comment: @GreenFinance Make sure you are running the latest version of Altair, which is currently 4.2.0

Comment: Thanks. I believe it is an issue with the Jupyter lab that I am working with. I ran it in the console and it works fine

Comment: @GreenFinance Great that it is working! Note that if you have updated Altair recently, you will need to make sure you close all notebooks with altair plots and then restart JupyterLab. Otherwise there can be some issues with it correctly updating to use the newer VegaLite scheme in the background.